# Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

last night I noticed I'm not able to change the attributes of elements in the layout from my main activity
so I built a new project and I had the same problem there too.
I could not find out what was wrong with my android studio so I'd appreciate it if someone with the same problem helps me out.
[as you see in the picture when I call a defined view from the layout in my activity its not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrjaU.jpg)  
the error will be: Unresolved reference: txtHello

Comment: i don't think there's anything wrong with your android studio, i just think synthetic imports aren't supported anymore. back to findViewById

Comment: so what should i exactly do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin Synthetic imports not working ?

Well, there's always the age-old alternative:

```
val foo: TextView = findViewById(R.id.your_id)
```

I believe synthetics have [been deprecated](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241) and I guess support for it has just now been completely removed

---

Alternatively, you can make use of [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), which is another alternative.

Enable it in your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

This generates a Binding object for your layout, so you can make use of it like this:

```
private lateinit var binding: YourLayoutNameBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = YourLayoutNameBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

then you have access to all views on the layout, through the binding:

```
binding.name.text = "foo"
```

Comment: it worked!
thanks
but why cant i use Synthetic imports anymore?
im sure it was working until last week.

Comment: @radmanhayati it has been deprecated for a while now, i too really like it, but it has downsides, so i think they've removed support for it entirely now with the last update of android studio

Comment: ok sir 
thanks for your time the answer was really useful

Comment: "has just now been completely removed" They only removed the Gradle plugin import for `kotlin-android-extensions" in new projects. You could add it yourself for new projects, although that's probably not a good idea since it's deprecated. Here's the official explanation of the deprecation: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html

Comment: yeah, my answer might have been a bit of an exaggeration, as you _can_ still add the plugin, but what i meant was that the plugin _has_ been completely removed by default, so you won't even have the option of seeing that it's deprecated, because it just won't work at all. typically, you'll see something is deprecated and you'll have to find an alternative, but here it's just enforced... kinda.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative you can look at is ViewBinding, a concept in Android that was introduced recently.

You should take a look for this

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

You cannot set view id directly for your use in app, instead you need `findViewById(R.id.idTextHello).setOnClickListener()`

That's how views are bind in application.

Comment: OP isn't talking about ViewBinding, they're talking about synthetic imports

Comment: Okay, then you need to stick  with findViewById

Comment: your answer is still valid, it's just an alternative and not what OP was talking about

Answer (score 1):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

but dont forget to apply kotlin extension

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your views via Kotlin Synthetics, which have been deprecated.
You can use ViewBinding instead.

Enable it in your module level build.gradle:

```
android {
...
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}
```

And then in your activity you can access views like :

```
private lateinit var _binding: ActivityNameBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    _binding = ActivityNameBinding(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

and then you can access your views like this:

```
_binding.btn_start.setOnClickListener {
...
}
```

For detailed understanding of ViewBinding, you can look into this article:

https://medium.com/geekculture/android-viewbinding-over-findviewbyid-389401b41706