# I was trying to use edit text id and it is showing errors , can you please help me

Tags: android, kotlin

I am beginner to Android Development using Kotlin and i was making a toast with my editText id but it is showing errors please help me.

image link[error activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ1sr.png)

[xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBE1B.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please reformat your post so the others can get a better image of your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand Google's recommended way of finding views from XML with `view binding` you may find a great article at [this page](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc)

The way you have started learning might create conflicts and null pointer exceptions. It is not the right way!