# simpler way of setting onClickListener for a button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple button for which I want to set an onclicklistener, I tried two approaches first by `findViewById` which works fine but can we access the `button` directly from kotlin code by its if

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Kotlin code

this approach works fine

```
val btnClickMe = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button) 
btnClickMe.setOnClickListener {
   // do something
}
```

When I tried to access the button directly by its id in the kotlin code it does not work

```
 button.setOnClickListener {
           //do something
        }
```

Error : unresolved reference Button

Am I trying something that is not possible? if not any suggestions on how to fix this please

thanks
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I tried to access the button directly by its id in the kotlin code it does not work

Is it possible ?

Yes, but...

What you're trying to achieve, by being able to reference the component directly, without using findViewById, is called Synthetic imports, which allows you to do this. The problem is that these are now deprecated and you should rather make use of viewBinding or just standard findViewById

---

Relevant info:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

[Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android/64717063#64717063)

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin synthetics allowed to access the components of the view directly by id, but it was deprecated. [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Now you should use View binding.

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

Comment: beat you by a few seconds :) but yes

Comment: I'll try to be faster next time, hehe :)