# Why is it not recognized in main activity when I create text view?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I created a TextView inside activity_main.xml and specified an ID for it, but when I go into MainActivity and click on that ID, it does not recognize TextView, and what does the red line under everything look like? How should I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you did.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with java, because you're using kotlin. that makes a big difference. secondly, [you can read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android/64717063#64717063)

Comment: Add this line `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to your app level build.gradle file then sync the project and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mainActivity does not know where the txt_test is coming from so you have to give it the reference.
I would recommend either use ViewBinding or use the old:

```
val txt = findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_textView)
```

Answer (score 1):

At gradle app

```
plugins {
   id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

> or

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

then your Activity Import this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in one of the posts above (for kotlin)
I converted a project from java code to kotlin and had to manually add the line

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

to my gradle file
example:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Edit note:
I get the complier message
The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

So evidently, Google is heading in a "view-binding" direction