# recyclerView - unresolved reference error in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The plugins mentioned below are there in the gradle file

**apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'**

the following dependency is also added in the same

**implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'**

Added this one as well;

**implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'**

the error is appearing when I am writing recyclerView in the OnCreate Funtion[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFhgr.png)

Could you please suggest, how the error can be resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

do check the apt version of rein the

```
  app->  project structure->  dependencies-> + symbol -> library dependencies
```

try it