# Kotlin error with importing variable 'button'

Tags: android, kotlin, variables

A super beginner question here, but I am stumped.

I am following the Kotlin Android tutorial video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRyvNKRkwbs) by tutorialsEU and he has started optimising the first section of code and I have followed exactly what he has done but am getting an error where his works.

Please see this screen shot for where I am stuck
[image: Please see this screen shot for where I am stuck]

When he highlights the red 'button' he has the option to 'import' (this worked on some previous examples as you can see from lines 3-7), but when I do it it just says 'create local variable 'button'  '
Is there a quick fix for why this is happening?

Here is the description of the Activity_Main screen
[image: 'Activity_Main']

Thanks for the help

Jon

Comment: Did you add the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Hi Gabriele
Thanks for the quick response. I am not sure what that means. I am literally a total beginner at this and am just following this youtube tutorial to get a basic understanding of the Android studio application and Kotlin. I will likely do a more in depth Kotlin course after this.

Would that be entered somewhere in the activity_main tab? I am not sure what the build.gradle file is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android)

Comment: The section where he does this and mine goes wrong is at 50:24 in the youtube video I linked.

He changes btn_click_me to button then has the option to 'import' when he rolls the cursor over it, whereas I am only given the option to create local variable. The purpose of this bit in the video appears to be to avoid needing to have the variable definition line for this function

Comment: @JonnyD in the app folder just check if the build.gradle file contains the line reported in the previous comment.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have searched for build.gradle in the Android Studio root folder but cannot see that file

Comment: Just refer to the link i've give you, you can just make use of findViewById

Comment: I looked in the plugin section of Android Studio. 'Kotlin' is already installed, but I cannot see any of the options listed below

It appears even this is way too advanced for me. Does anyone recommend a good beginner tutorial for learning Kotlin?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks, I will have a look at the link.

Comment: @JonnyD It is not related to kotlin. It is related to the android plugin. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I located the build.gradle file. How do I open it to edit its contents?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti The android gradle plugin version is 4.1.3 and the Gradle version is 6.5

Comment: @JonnyD Just open it in AS. It is text file.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have accessed the build.gradle file and the line you mentionmed is not in there. Please can you explain how/where this needs to be entered? Can it be on any line? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: @JonnyD just check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968584/2016562) below.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I see the text below, but do I just copy paste that to the bottom of the code in the build.gradle file?

Comment: @JonnyD At the top of the file. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#module-level)

Comment: If you want to find a file (or anything else), tap shift twice and start typing!

Answer (score 2):

It requires the **Kotlin Android Extensions**. Add the plugin in the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Also please note that the Kotlin Android Extensions is now **deprecated**, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported. You should [**migrate**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) to the new library for [**View Binding**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

In any case you can use the "old" method:

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

Comment: which, is deprecated :)

Answer (score 0):

U can't just access the id: button in your kotlin file. The current way of doing this is to declare

```
android {
   ...
   buildFeatures {
      viewBinding true
   }
}
```

in your gradle file. Now rebuild your project.
After that you can get a binding of type Activity(your_name)Binding in your Activity file:
`private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding`

in onCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

So gradle creates a binding Java class for every layout xml.
You can access the button via
`binding.button`

Comment: It is not exact. You can do it using the Kotlin Android Extensions (released in 2017). It is now depracated but you can use it.

Comment: No, the KAE isn't available in an empty project. You either use findViewById() or update your project by KAE or viewBinding, with viewBinding being the most recent one

Comment: I didn't watch the full tutorial he was following

Answer (score 0):

Either you should apply plugin `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' put it top of your app.gradle file, or sometimes it looks like this:

[image]

And import `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main`

But  kotlinx.android extension is **deprecated** so far, so you can migrate to viewbinding
[read this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Or just use old findViewById method like:

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses guys, I will try to test all the suggestions, although a lot of it means nothing to me atm as I literally started this today and have never used Kotlin before :)

Comment: The viewbinding is an android component, btw, one of the newest and most fresh view building component is jetpackCompose, read 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose?gclid=CjwKCAjwjbCDBhAwEiwAiudBy5c4hDUcBgLsHaFwzLvmaE1LodynkEq4ANaYAw1LP3T-Otf-fCmS5RoCub0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds