# Can I use kotlinx.android.synthetic when migrating to Kotlin 1.4.32

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Try to `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.#####` and get `Unresolved reference: synthetic`, I try clean, rebuild, reimport plugin - . Should I migrate to data binding or is there a way to use "extensions" in Kotlin 1.4.32?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android

Comment: So...it's sad.  Now I have to rewrite the whole project :(

Comment: you don't have to rewrite it, you can still add the plugin, but it IS deprecated, so you should probably consider removing it