# Android kotlin textView name not detected in activity file?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have created a textView in the android XML file and in kotlin while creating an activity,
See the code below:

textViewName.setText("Hello")

Here the textViewName is showing error.
But in Kotlin is it necessary to give the findViewById reference to the text view to work?

Comment: can you share your Kotlin  and XML code?

Comment: `But in Kotlin is it necessary to give the findViewById reference to the text view to work?` if you're not using synthetics (which are deprecated) yes, it is. or use view binding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use Kotlin's extension (deprecated and discouraged but can still be used).

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'

    //add this to your app gradle
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

You can now reference the textView directly on the Kotlin code without `findViewById()`.
The other option is to go with **Data** and **View Binding**